# How to create json from a list of dataframes in a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, to-json

I have a list with multiple dataframes in it. I want create json for each df in list using for loop.

I tried,

```
dfsize=[df df df]

for dfs in dfsize:
    dfs.to_json('areca{dfs}.json').format(dfs)
```

Was met with the error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'

Is there a way to achieve this?

Also tried:

I tried

```
dfs.to_json('areca{dfs}.json'.format(dfs))
```

but got the error:

> dfs.to_json('areca{dfs}.json'.format(dfs.index))
>
> KeyError: 'dfs'

Comment: `dfsize=[df df df]` should be `dfsize=[df, df, df]` right, change the line to `dfs.to_json('areca{}.json'.format(name_of_dfs))`, the `format` function is for string, so it right after your string, not after the `to_json` function,

Comment: example: `'areca{}.json'.format('test')` -> `arecatest.json`, so you probably need a way to determine the name of df

Comment: Seem like you miss a character ')' in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pandas.DataFrame.to_json returns None. This is causing the error. Format should be inside. Try this,

```
dfsize=[df df df]

for dfs in dfsize:
    dfs.to_json('areca{dfs}.json'.format(dfs))
```